# SendKeys Issue with Gma.UserActivityMonitor (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, sendkeys

I'm creating an automation tool for sending text, using `SendKeys.Send()`, to various other windows than the sending windows forms application. I'm setting the tool up to "type" with hotkey commands using the Gma.UserActivityMonitor library available here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx

My problem is that when I use the hotkey to handle the keypress to trigger the typing, sometimes it still allows the keypress to slip through.

I attempted to spin up a new thread and use sendkeys there, but I got an error that I should use `SendKeys.SendWait` due to the target application not accepting input.

So my question can be answered in one of two ways:

1) In which direction can I look for more information about multi-threading and using sendkeys?

2) How can I make sure that the trigger keypress is correctly inhibited by the hookmanager in the library?

I'm allowing the user to build a dictionary that's keyed by different letters, so different letters send different strings to the target application.
Relevant Code:

```
private void HookManager_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    //code to generate tValue from the pressed key
    if (tAutoTyperDictionary.ContainsKey(tValue))
    {
        //Should prevent the key from being passed to the window
        //works sometimes
        e.Handled = true;
        AutoType();
    }
}

private void AutoType()
{
    int tCount = 0;
    string tLine = tAutoTyperDictionary[tCurrentAutotypeKey];

    //I remove the listener to prevent it calling itself
    HookManager.KeyPress -= new KeyPressEventHandler(HookManager_KeyPress);
    while (tCount < tLine.Length)
    {
        SendKeys.Send(tLine[tCount].ToString());
        Thread.Sleep(10);
        tCount++;
    }

    HookManager.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(HookManager_KeyPress);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried SendKeys.SendWait(string keys) instead of Thread.Sleep(10)?

SendWait waits until the sent keys are cleared before proceeding.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a static thread class that I wrote that may be useful in this case:

```
public static class threadClass
    {
        private static Thread _thread;
        public static Thread thread
        {
            get { return _thread; }
        }
        public static void startThread()
        {
            _thread = new Thread(delegate() { });
            _thread.Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I will hopefully get to check out both your suggestions this weekend. Thanks for offering assistance. =)